# Updates failing on Server and Workstation LTS 16.04.3

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

Recently when updating I get errors similar to the ones below, I usually run `apt-get update` and `upgrade` for both the desktop and server. I also get a failed update with software updater on the desktop.

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages 
Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages.xz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you running this command as root or with sudo?

Comment: Can you provide the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: Yes I'm using sudo -s, won't let me edit and add the files too many links

Comment: If someone can tell me where to find a list of working sources or a way to submit me sources.list file. I would greatly appreciate it.